# VB.Net - Select an Excel Worksheet, after using a Browse button

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I have a Browse button code, that when I browse to an Excel file, I then want to be able to select a particular worksheet for that file manually so I can then import that particular sheet into a Datagridview.
I am trying to use either a combobox or a listbox.

My plans are to use the Browse button to populate a Textbox, then via that textbox, select a worksheet, then import it to a Datagridview for review, before exporting it to a SQL Database table.

I have to code for the browse button, I can import the file to a dataviewgrid,and export it to SQL. But only if the Excel file has a Single "predefined" worksheet name.
I need the worksheet selectable after the browse but before the Datagridview import.
This is my Browse Button Code.I am guessing its to simplistic for the takes and must load the file first.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.Title = "Open File Dialog"
    fd.InitialDirectory = "H:\COST ACCTG\Inventory\"
    fd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    fd.FilterIndex = 2
    fd.RestoreDirectory = True

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        strFileName = fd.FileName
    End If

    TextBox1.Text = strFileName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the path of the Excel spreadsheet you can set up a connection string and find out what tables (Sheets) exist and add each table to a combobox for selection:

```
Dim excelConnectionString as string
Dim  mySheets as Datatable
Dim myConnection as OleDB.OleDBConnection

Try
    excelConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        excelPath & "; Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""

    myConnection = New OleDBConnection(excelConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()

    mySheets = myConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDB.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

    For Each row as DataRow in mySheets.Rows
        ComboboxExcelSheetsToImport.Items.Add(row("TABLE_NAME")
    Next row

Catch ex as Exception
    'Exception Handling
End Try
```

Once the desired table (Sheet) is selected you can use an SQL statement that includes the selected Excel Sheet to bring in the data.  Bad example below:

```
myCommand = new OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & selectedSheet & "]", myConnection)
```